# If I use the spell Shapechange to become a Kalaraq Quori and use Soul Binding, is the creature's soul still imprisoned when I turn back?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, shapeshifting, soul

The [Kalaraq Quori](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/493174-kalaraq-quori) has the following attack:

> Soul Binding.
> Melee Spell Attack: +13 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 29 (4d10 + 7) necrotic damage. A creature reduced to 0 hit points from this attack dies and has its soul imprisoned in one of the quori's eyes. The target can't be revived by any means short of a wish spell until the quori is destroyed.

My question is, when the Shapechange spell ends, does this effect end or remain?

Do the effects on the stat block stop working when the stat block disappears, and/or does Shapechange ending count as the quori being "destroyed"? Or, alternatively, is there some other reason the effect would end that I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This is entirely up to the DM.

There is no direct text explicitly stating one way or the other whether unpolymorphing counts as 'destroying' the form.

It is a reasonable conclusion that something that ends if a thing is destroyed also ends if it *ceases to exist.*

It is *also* a reasonable conclusion to decide that when the eye ceased to exist, the soul within it ceased to exist.

It very much depends on whether or not the narrative (DM) suggests that the soul in question was plucked from existence with the creature, or if the creature's removal from existence ejected the soul into the afterlife.

If your DM has a sufficient headache trying to sort this out for themselves, beware of a third option; you now have a soul stored in the eye of a living, no-longer polymorphed creature who isn't meant to have a soul in its eye, and the soul wants out- or worse, it wants *control*.

Comment: Personally, I honestly think the last option you listed is the most appropriate way to handle this, though also obviously the one most based on DM intervention. I just don't feel like shapechange ending counts as "destroyed" because the being that is "the quori" still exists, just in a different form - it wouldn't be destruction for similar reasons that, say, polymorphing the quori presumably wouldn't free the souls. But that would mean that the eye and the imprisoned soul transforms back into the player character as well, which would reasonably have consequences.

Answer (score 2):

### There is no longer a prison

The prison is specifically “one of the quori's eyes”, when you transform back there is no longer a quori’s eye. No prison, no prisoner. The soul is freed.

Answer (score 1):

### The soul should be set free

The quori's ability says:

> The target can't be revived by any means short of a wish spell **until the quori is destroyed**.

This condition, even though the soul is imprisoned in one of the quori's eyes, does not talk about the eye. It plainly states that *wish it the only means* to retrieve the soul, until the quori itself is **destroyed**. So what does destroyed mean?

#### Use of "destroyed" in the rules

There are examples in the rules that show the rules do not consider attack or damage a requirement for destruction, and instead also use the term "destroy" more in the wider sense of "end the existence of something". On page 221 DMG, under "Destroying Artifacts", the rules state:

> An artifact must be destroyed in some special way. Otherwise, it is impervious to damage. Each artifact has a weakness by which its **creation can be undone**

This is followed by examples such as dropping an artifact into a river, bathing it in blood, or returning it to its creator who must touch it -- neither of which is an attack or dealing damage.

So, based on this rules precedent, anything that *ends the existence* of the quori or means that  **its creation is undone** and should be considered as destruction. Therefore, reverting from quori form counts as destruction of that form, and sets the creature's soul free to be available for revival.

This result also has the common sense side benefit of not needing to explain how the soul can remain imprisoned in an eye that no longer exists. If your DM disagrees with this, they are of course free to overrule this and declare the soul can only be revived with a *wish*.